# Validating a group of elements in RichFaces 3.3.x / JSF

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have a requirement where I have three <rich:listShuttle> elements from which **at least one** item must be selected **between the three items**, i.e. two <rich:listShuttle> elements could be empty as long as there is an element selected in the other.

I am using **RichFaces 3.3.2** and am not currently able to upgrade to 4.

I have tried using a validator on a hidden field which validates the state of the <rich:listShuttle> (I have them bound in a backing bean). However, the backing UIListShuttle is not updated before validation takes place.

Thanks in advance.